# QML ListView data items overwritten (newbie)

Tags: listview, model, delegates, qml

Questions:

1. What am I missing -- display items should be on separate lines?
2. Why do the two delgate usages below give different results?
3. What should I read to understand this?

Thank you.

```
import QtQuick 2.15

import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("ListView Overwrite")

    ListModel {
        id: dataSource_1
        ListElement { name: "rock" }
        ListElement { name: "paper" }
        ListElement { name: "scissors" }
    }

    Component {
        id: delegateItem
        Item {
            Text { text: name }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        model: dataSource_1
        //delegate: Text { text: name } // only "rock" displayed
        delegate: delegateItem  // rock, paper, scissors displayed, overwritten
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good explanation for your issue can be found in the doc of [`Item.implicitHeight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop) :

> The default implicit size for most items is 0x0, however some items have an inherent implicit size which cannot be overridden, for example, Image and Text.

You did not give a size to your `ListView` so it currently has an implicit size of 0x0.

It means that paper/scissors delegates are considered outside of the view and are not rendered.

Either give an explicit height to the `ListView` or simply specify `anchors.fill: parent` for example.

It's the same problem for the delegates stacked on each other using your "Component" based solution. The issue here is that the `Text` is wrapped around an `Item` that do not have a size specified, so each delegate has an implicit height equal to `0`. Remove the `Item` wrapper and your texts will be correctly positioned, since `Text` has an inherent `implicitHeight`.

Comment: Note that this "Component" based solution is not needed, your original solution with `delegate: Text {...}` is fine!

Comment: I have no reputation, so can't upvote this answer.  I would if I could.  Thank you for telling the me the exact problem -- no height on the ListView -- and providing solutions.  Specifying the height solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to help! Even if you can't upvote answers yet, you can accept answers on your questions